# could not run job in sql server agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-agent

I am trying to execute a job from SQL Server Agent however receiving the error:

```
The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

The Sql server 2016 with Sql server Agent and SSIS where a credential account `proxy` is linking to `windows admin account`. The proxy is set `SSIS package excecution`:

[image]

The job has only 1 step to run SSIS package. This package is developed/tested/deployed from VS 2016+Data tools.

[image]

Here is the step:

[image]

and the error:

[image]

Right click on the job to view History. Here is the error:

```
Executed as user: MACHINE_NAME\admin_user. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 13.0.1601.5 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  2:15:10 PM  Failed to execute IS server package because of error 0x80131904. Server: xxx, Package path: \SSISDB\Practise 1\SSIS 1\Package.dtsx, Environment reference Id: NULL.  Description: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.  Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider  Started:  2:15:10 PM  Finished: 2:15:10 PM  Elapsed:  0.188 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.
```

Comment: I suggest you right cilck SSMS / Run As. Run it as that user and try and log into SSMS and see if you get the same error.

Comment: I am running the SSMS in the same machine with the SQL server instance using administrator account. No luck with `run as`.

Answer (score 1):

The Sql server agent, which is running on the local machine, could not resolve the server name `tcp:xxx.cloudapp.azure.com` in the step. As the agent is local so just set the server name to `.`. Resolved.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for returning with your answer. Note this piece of information was not in you original question.